# WordPress adminbar missing in front end

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I recently download the theme from [underscore me](http://underscores.me/). After working for a while I notice the admin bar is not showing at front end even when I am logged in? I tried solving it myself doing some research but no luck.

I have done following things to resolve:

1. check `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` function in header.php and footer.php respectively.
2. check any function like this `function remove_admin_bar() { return false; }`
3. check any css to hide `#adminbar{display: none; }` or anything related to admin bar
4. Verify the checkbox is checked in user profile option "Show Toolbar when viewing site"
5. Logged in, logged out many times. Delete cache etc etc
6. `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`
7. Disable plugins one by one

Done almost everything but failed. Then I change the theme to twenty15/14/13/12 and there it is showing properly. Then I realized it has to do something with the theme. So I compare this new theme from underscore and twenty15 and find out that following js files are not included in new theme.

1. function.js
2. html5.js
3. color-scheme-control.js and two more others

If i search for adminbar keyword in function.js then there is a whole lot of code for that. First, how can I get back admin bar or does it has something to do with the missing files or maybe underscoreme has left them for purpose to show the admin bar other way around.
Also mywordpress version is 4.2.2

Comment: Is it loaded in the DOM? ( Do you see it in the HTML code )

Comment: if you mean by viewing page source then no it isn't showning there too

Comment: FWIW I just downloaded a test theme from underscores.me and it does still show the admin bar for me on a stock install of WordPress 4.2.2.

Comment: That said, the test theme I downloaded does not have the JavaScript files you mentioned.

Comment: @doublesharp you were right. after your comment  i tried the same theme  with new installation and it worked there. Again checking deeply, it was my custom options tree conflict. Thank you guys for your time. Should be more careful next time. Funny though seeing the vast cirteria for that one single admin bar. Would be more easy, if there would be some specific place to check for this type of error. Anything can conflict to anything. Not an ideal thing.